# extract data sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

Example: Below is the string(sentence) in field and I want to extract the specific data from the below patterns using select query in different fields:

i )

Input :
/a03/infor/current/server/infa_sh/ScriptFil/infa_common/adap_main **'FI_RE_PRJ' 'wf_RE_ACC_TIE_HIS_MNT_EN_AM'**

Output :
Select  query to fetch FI_RE_PRJ and wf_RE_ACC_TIE_HIS_MNT_EN_AM

Other pattern I have is :

Input :

$SCRIPTS/run_in.ksh -f **FI_FLE_PRJ** -wait **wf_FI_SV_CNCL_RP_BAS_KF**

Output :
Select query to fetch FI_FLE_PRJ and  wf_FI_SV_CNCL_RP_BAS_KF from input

Comment: It is unclear (at least, to me) what you have and what you want to get as a result.

Comment: post the code you've tried to match

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, it seems that - in the first example - you want to get values between single quotes. But, which rule(s) apply to the second example? Why is FI_FLE_PRJ so *special* (because you wrote it bold? That's not good enough). Also, can you have not two but maybe only one value to extract, or 3, 7, etc.?

Comment: Don't edit your question to ask multiple questions. Look for a pattern for your first input format in this question (as per the original) and ask a second question to ask how to match the second input format.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '''(.*?)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS first,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '''(.*?)''', 1, 2, NULL, 1) AS second
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1 ) AS quote1,
       SUBSTR( value, pos3 + 1, pos4 - pos3 - 1 ) AS quote2
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '''', 1, 1) AS pos1,
         INSTR(value, '''', 1, 2) AS pos2,
         INSTR(value, '''', 1, 3) AS pos3,
         INSTR(value, '''', 1, 4) AS pos4
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '/a03/infor/current/server/infa_sh/ScriptFil/infa_common/adap_main ''FI_RE_PRJ'' ''wf_RE_ACC_TIE_HIS_MNT_EN_AM''' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| QUOTE1 | QUOTE2 |
| --- | --- |
| FI_RE_PRJ | wf_RE_ACC_TIE_HIS_MNT_EN_AM |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hFWs7FzK)